# Cloudflare Origin Certificate configuration on Azure APIM

Tags: ssl, cloudflare, azure-api-management, client-certificates, apim

What I need to do:
Ensure that traffic between Cloudflare and my origin server is encrypted with certificate + key. If not, connection should be refused with 403

I have generated certificate in the "origin server" section, and uploaded the cerificate and key as a single .pfx file to Azure APIM (my origin server), but Cloudflare is not properly including the certificate and key during a call to `api.my-domain.com/my_api` and I'm getting the 403 from Azure APIM.

Settings:

- I have full mode on `mydomain.com`
- I have a rule that enforces full strict mode on `api.mydomain.com/*`
- In the origin server section I have a cert generated for `mydomain.com` and `*.mydomain.com`
- In the origin server section I have another cert generated for `api.mydomain.com` and `*.api.mydomain.com`

Behavior:

- I have debugged to ensure certificates are properly generated, installed, and configured on Azure APIM.
- Conclusion is that Cloudflare is not presenting the cert + key to Azure APIM

Guess on reason from my part:

1. Either the origin server certificate for `*.mydomain.com` is included in the call to `api.mydomain.com`, instead of the certificate for `api.mydomain.com`
2. Or they key is not included in the call. Only the cert is.

Anyone done this setup and/or know the problem?